# Filter wrong database records in a DataGridView control (Visual Studio 2005)(Visual Basic) (Normalization)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, ms-access-2007, normalization

I have this database and I need to load it with a visual basic form in Visual Studio 2005.

The database has 6 tables and they contain wrong data that I must filter when loading the database in the form.

A quick example:

First table is Category, which has 3 fields (id, name, description). In one record I have 2a for id (a numeric only field) and in other record I have m1lk for name (a string only field).

When I click a button I load the database into a DataGridView control. How do I stop visual basic from loading into the DataGridView control those records that have invalid data (like in my example).

I have try with SQL queries using WHERE and LIKE, like in

```
SELECT   IdCategoría, NombreCategoría, Descripción
FROM     Categorías
WHERE    (NombreCategoría LIKE '[!l]%') AND (IdCategoría LIKE '[!abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz]')
```

but it's really difficult to filter things like Angel* and P3ter and Hood8, all at the same time...

Please show me a example code in your answer so I can try it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: -1, does not show any research effort. Rather than "show me a example code in your answer so I can try it", try editing your question to include code *you* wrote and tried, so we can show you where you went wrong. (That will also encourage me to cancel my "-1".)

Comment: StackOverflow has a FAQ. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: Thanks for posting your SQL statement. I removed my -1 for your question, but I flagged your unconstructive comment.

Comment: @Ashir: Please maintain a civil tone. You've engaged in comment flame wars before on SO, and this is not welcome. Sarcastic remarks should be used only when you're certain that they're justified and/or funny, and in this case it is neither. Catcall's original downvote was quite legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a column in an MS Access table using a numeric data type, it simply won't allow values like "2a". But text columns *will* allow values like "m1lk", because "m1lk" is a valid string.

**Quick workaround**

To select only those values that can be interpreted as numbers, use the isnumeric() function. You need a SQL statement along these lines.

```
SELECT your-column-list
FROM some-table
WHERE isnumeric(numeric-column-having-bad-data)
```

Be aware that expressions like `isnumeric("2e5")` and `isnumeric("2d5")` will return True. VBA interprets both "2d5" and "2e5" as 2^5 ("two to the fifth power").

To select data that contains no numerals at all, use a regular expression like this. (I'm not certain you're trying to do this.)

```
SELECT your-column-list
FROM some-table
WHERE some-column-name Not Like "*[0-9]*";
```

Comment: Yes, normaly, a normalized database (or a well defined) should not accept nor contain data types other than those already defined by it's data type, but this database it's not normalized, that's why it has things like 2a or m1lk. I try `NOT LIKE '*[0-9]*'` but it's not working, I still get P3ter and Wooh8 and records like that...

Comment: @Ashir: "Well defined" is the right term; "normalized" means something completely different when you're talking about SQL databases. The expression `Not Like "*[0-9]*"` does indeed eliminate the values "P3ter" and "Wooh8"; make sure you're applying it to the right column.